# Add data rows to XML table in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to figure out how to store data using C#.

I'm new to C# data storage, having used PHP and MySQL to do this kind of thing in the past. After doing some research, it seems that using XML serialization is the way to go but I'm not quite sure of all the details.

So far, I've created my table with several columns:

```
private void SerializeDataSet()
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));

    // Creates a DataSet for user info
    DataSet vault = new DataSet("vault");
    DataTable table_users = new DataTable("users");
    DataColumn last_name = new DataColumn("last_name");
    DataColumn first_name = new DataColumn("first_name");
    DataColumn birthdate = new DataColumn("birthdate");
    DataColumn role = new DataColumn("role");
    table_users.Columns.Add(last_name);
    table_users.Columns.Add(first_name);
    table_users.Columns.Add(birthdate);
    table_users.Columns.Add(role);

    // adds table
    vault.Tables.Add(table_users);

    // serialized table
    string filename = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources) + "Vault_Tec_storage";
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    ser.Serialize(writer, vault);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Now what I can't figure out how to do, is actually add the data to that table. For example, if I wanted a method to process a user registration for John Doe, born 10/15/1975 with role "0," how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store your data in XML files? Wouldn't a database engine like MySQL, SQLite work better? You should take a look at the ADO.NET framework, and also at the higher abstraction layers later (like Entity Framework or NHibernate).

Comment: Probably, but I'm not sure how to bundle it with my application so the user doesn't have to download and configure MySQL. I'm pretty new to C# in general and haven't done much development in about a year. I'd learn how to do that but this is just a side project right now.

Comment: If you want a database bundled with your application I suggest using SQLite, take a look at some tutorials, it is quite easy and in my opinion easier than working with XML files. Try this tutorial: [getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try the DataSet ReadXml()

Usage is something like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C://filepath.xml"))
{
     byte[] fullByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
     MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(fullByte);
     mStream.Position = 0;
     dataSet.ReadXml(mStream);

     /*
     while DEBUGGING, you'll notice here that your `dataSet` is now populated by
     collection of tables. These table came for each sub nodes followed with an
     internal ID as relationship between nodes. From here, you may add values in 
     your table like the usage below.
     */

     // ex. if Table is like this
     // Name | Age
     // John | 09/10/2015
     DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];

     dt.Rows.Add(
       // array of objects
       new object[] { "New John", "09/11/2015" }     
     );

     //OR

     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr["Name"] = "New John";
     dr["Age"] = "09/11/2015";
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

hopefully this helps, if you have a specific case you're struggling at, kindly line it under the comment section, we'll help you out.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void SerializeDataSet()
        {
            // Creates a DataSet for user info
            DataSet vault = new DataSet("vault");
            DataTable table_users = new DataTable("users");
            table_users.Columns.Add("last_name", typeof(string));
            table_users.Columns.Add("first_name", typeof(string));
            table_users.Columns.Add("birthdate", typeof(DateTime));
            table_users.Columns.Add("role", typeof(int));

            // adds table
            vault.Tables.Add(table_users);
            table_users.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Doe", "John", DateTime.Parse("10/15/1975"), 0 });

            // serialized table
            string filename = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources) + "Vault_Tec_storage";
            vault.WriteXml(filename);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out this evening.